# Tomcat won't start on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat

I have this confusing situation. My maven java web application starts when i run `mvn clean install org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run-war` from console. But when i configure Tomcat on eclipse and start the server i get the following exception:

```
    Caused by:javax.persistence.PersistenceException[PersistenceUnit: persistence-unit] class or package not found
    .....
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.package.MyClass
    ......
```

My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence>
   <persistence-unit name="persistence-unit">
       <class>com.my.package.MyClass</class>
       <class>com.my.package.MyClassTwo</class>
       <class>com.my.package.MyClassThree</class>
       <properties>
           <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
       </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Now all the classes defined in persistence.xml exist and can be reached using ctrl + click in persistence.xml, so it is clear the packages and class names are 100% correct. Searching arround i have tried the solution at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18073429 . When I comment out the class tags i get no startup exceptions, but the application doesn't truly start as i get a differrent exception when trying to access the app:

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Expression Error: Named Object: entityConverter not found.
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
```

This entityConverter is annotated with `@FacesConverter(value = "entityConverter")`, which is proper handling of such converter, so i don't see the problem here also.

Now the main confusion is that the application starts and runs fine on eclipse using other pc with exactly same tomcat instance (copied tomcat, copied settings etc.) and it a few times, randomly worked on the machine where i get these exceptions, but i did alt+f5 project refresh on eclipse and it stopped working again. No settings are changed between the two machines (building using same repository, same revision). Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you use JPA for persistent provider?

Comment: If its runs on cmd prompt not in eclipse then its eclipse's build path issue. Run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` then refresh the eclipse project then try.

Comment: Try with new eclipse and also new workspace. (Does eclipse identify the imported project as a maven project?)

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what caused this, but it was fixed using sura2k's advice. Switched to Eclipse Mars, created new workspace, configured new server and everything is working as expected.